# Create table from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

pandas is so popular, so many questions and answers so I have a huge mess in my head

you can see it by triple 'so' in one sentence

I have pandas df made from IMDB tsv files - there three columns - 'season', 'episode', 'rating'.
I want to receive a "rating map" with season numbers as columns and episode numbers as rows.
I tried to draw it in the picture.

```
df_episodes = DataFrame({'season':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'episode':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'rating':[3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

Is there any common way to make this conversion?

Started with making new dataframe

```
df = DataFrame(columns=[df_episodes.season])
```

but don't know how to make column names unique - now I have '1', '1','1','2','2',...

then I planned to iterate within df

[image]

Comment: `df_episodes.pivot('episode','season','rating')`

Comment: huh, so easy. thank you.
that is my bad that for 2 hrs searching I missed 'pivot' keyword